# Get date when MPMediaItem was added to iTunes library

Tags: ios, itunes, mpmediaitem

Is it possible? I haven't found anything like this in MPMediaItemProperty... strings. Maybe private API?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Looking through the documentation, the methods list doesn't have a field for it.  This leaves you with the option of extending `MPMediaItem` with a new `MPMediaItemProperty` for the 'date added' field yourself.  Of course, this only works going forward.

Alternatively, you could parse the iTunes Library XML item and compare fields to the `MPMediaItem` you're using.  There is a `key` tag for 'Date Modified' that has the conventional filesystem 'Date Modified' information (presumably from when the file was added to iTunes), but which is basically when the file was ripped or added unless you're modifying your MP3 files.  So it's not strictly what you're looking for, but it's the closest general analogue I can think of.

You may want to see if there is a way of finding the Track ID key directly from the file or `MPMediaItem` as well which may give you a faster search through the iTunes Library XML file.  Try the `MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID`-based methods---one of these should correspond to the hex identifier in the 'Persistent ID' `key` field of the iTunes Library XML file.

Comment: @ascentruy - You suggest that it is possible to extend MPMediaItem with a new MPMediaItemProperty for the 'date added' field. Could you elaborate how you would programmatically detect the when a new media item is added to the library and how you would extend MPMediaItem with a new MPMediaItemProperty? Are you specifying a solution that is for an iMac or for an iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38826548/899490

> As of iOS 10 it appears we have access to two dateAdded properties.
>
> **Note:** iOS 10 is still in beta (4) at time of writing so things could change.
>
> As a Date object:
>
> ```
> MPMediaItem.dateAdded
> ```
>
> and as a String:
>
> ```
> MPMediaItemPropertyDateAdded
> ```
>
> source:
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/iOS10APIDiffs/Objective-C/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: Seems like it made it into the release version.