# Is it possible to get the Date Added info about a MPMediaItem with Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I would like to get the date a song was added to an Itunes Library in order to sort the songs from the last added to first added.

There is a similar property key (MPMediaItemPropertyLastPlayedDate) with the "Last Played" info which sort the songs in the same way that I want to but I can't find a similar function for the "Last Added" info. 
Is there anything to do what I want?

Comment: Reference [MPMediaItem Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/User_Defined_Property_Keys) The last added or modified is not an option.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38826548/899490 iOS 10 appears to add some date added properties